# Is `TweedieRegressor` a completely general GLM solution?

Tags: regression, logistic, generalized-linear-model, scikit-learn

I consider `sklearn`'s [`TweedieRegressor`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.TweedieRegressor.html) a general solution for all types of regression, as it is a GLM model. If I understand well, that means any regression type can be obtained by appropriately parametrizing `TweedieRegressor`.

*Logistic regression* is a special case of GLM.
I guess, to have logistic regression there should be a `logit` value (or something like that) for the `link` parameter, but there is no such possibility.

Can `TweedieRegressor` be parametrized to do logistic regression?
If yes, how? If not, why not?

Comment: Your presumption about "all types of regression" is incorrect: this software can only model a limited (but still large) number of response distributions.  Among the common ones not included are Binomial, Multinomial, and Negative Binomial. That's why `sklearn` offers a separate function for those distributions!

Comment: It might be worth noting that under the hood, sklearn uses the `GeneralizedLinearModel` class to do most of the heavy lifting, and `TweedieRegressor` does [very little else](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/95119c13af77c76e150b753485c662b7c52a41a2/sklearn/linear_model/_glm/glm.py#L650), so aside from the modules not being public, one should be able to build an arbitrary GLM(?).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No.  A GLM is [characterized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_linear_model#Model_components) by its link function *and* its target distribution.  `TweedieRegressor` assumes a Tweedie distribution for the latter, which [do not include](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tweedie_distribution#Related_distributions) the Bernoulli distribution needed for logistic regression.

Answer (score 10):

Logistic regression corresponds to a Binomial distribution, a member of the exponential family, so in that sense it is nested within the [Exponential Dispersion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_dispersion_model) class of models. The $\mathrm{Tweedie}(\mu, \sigma^2)$ family specifically is also contained within $\mathrm{ED}$, but imposes the mean-variance relationship

\begin{align*}
\mu &= \mathbf{E}[Y]\\
\operatorname{var}(Y) &= \sigma^2 \mu^p.
\end{align*}

This cannot work for logistic regression because the Binomial needs $$\operatorname{var}(Y) = np(1-p) = n\mathbf{E}[Y](1-\mathbf{E}[Y]).$$